# Adding Multiple Inputs Not Working Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple issue that I might just not be thinking through. I am trying to add together several input fields (which are all formatted numbers like 2.00, 3.00, etc.).

But using the following script:

```
 var sum = parseFloat(0).toFixed(2);
    //using an iterator find and sum the values of checked checkboxes
    $(".amountCheckbox:checked").each(function() {
        var input = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.amountInput').val());
        console.log(input.toFixed(2));
      sum += input.toFixed(2);
      console.log(sum);
    });
    return sum;
```

It returns as 02.003.00 rather than 5.00. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: toFixed() returns a string, so you're just doing string concatenation

Comment: Remove all `.toFixed()` from your code and just add it once with `return` like `return sum.toFixed()`, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string so `+` concatenates rather than add the numbers. Give the [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method a try:

```
return $(".amountCheckbox:checked").closest('tr').find('.amountInput')
.map((index,input) => +input.value).get()
.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    const sum = $(".amountCheckbox:checked")
    .closest('tr').find('.amountInput')
    .map((index,input) => +input.value).get()
    .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
    
    console.log( sum.toFixed(2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amountInput" value="2.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amountInput" value="5.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amountInput" value="1.00"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="amountInput" value="2.20"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

ToFixed will convert the value to a string, so you are just concatenating.

I think what you want to do is sum up all the values before calling `toFixed` and call `toFixed` after to format the value as a fixed precision value.

```
 var sum = 0;

    //using an iterator find and sum the values of checked checkboxes
    $(".amountCheckbox:checked").each(function() {
        var input = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.amountInput').val());
        console.log(input.toFixed(2));
      sum += input;
      console.log(sum);
    });
    return sum.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
//using an iterator find and sum the values of checked checkboxes
$(".amountCheckbox:checked").each(function() {
  var input = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.amountInput').val());
  console.log(input.toFixed(2));
  sum += input;
  console.log(sum);
});
return sum.toFixed(2);
```

`toFixed()` would return string not numeric value.

Comment: As `var sum = parseFloat(0).toFixed(2);` at first line so `sum` will be `string`, so `sum += input` will be string concatenation & it will return incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```js
$('table').on('change input','input',ev=>{
 $('#res').text($(".amountCheckbox:checked").get().reduce((a,c)=>
   +$(c).closest('tr').find('.amountInput').val()+a, 0).toFixed(2))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td><td>A</td>
<td><input value="1.2345" class="amountInput"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td><td>B</td>
<td><input value="13.114" class="amountInput"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="amountCheckbox"></td><td>C</td>
<td><input value="3.6345" class="amountInput"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>total: <span id="res"></span>
```

The summation happens in the `.reduce()` function and is done over all table rows where the checkbox is checked. Each input value is converted to float by applying the unary operator `+`. The summation result is then rounded and converted to a string again in `.toString(2)`.